# c++ passing big vectors as output

Tags: c++, performance, vector, containers

I have several big vector (roughly with a million elements), lets say `vector<int> v` generated in a function or a class member function. I want to use this vector outside of this function/member efficiently, i.e., avoid copying it entirely when I pass it as an output

```
vector<int> make_vect() {
    vector<int> v(1e6); 
    ...      // some analysis
    return v;
}

int main() {
vector<int> v = make_vect();
}
```

I know that I can use a pointer to this vector `vector<int> *v` instead, but that would complicate things a little bit (for instance I have to delete them manually and so on). I was wondering how the code above behaves if I don't use a reference or pointer.

Apart from copying issue, in the code above when is the allocated memory freed? Is the content never deleted unless I call v.clear()? or it automatically deletes them when there's no variable pointing to the container left?

Comment: Is this C++11 or later? Are there complications with trying and measuring?

Comment: Pas the resulting vector as a non-constant reference argument?

Comment: you don't want to use pointers/references, yet avoid copy (by using local vector). Why don't you use a static/global one?

Comment: You only need to `delete` them if they're allocated dynamically, which is not happening in your example. Non-`const` references are what you want.

Comment: "Delete them manually". We normally don't do that. having `std::unique_ptr` and all. But it doesn't even matter, the compiler should optimize out copying when you return by value.

Comment: Would [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) apply here?  This is where I could use some education.

Comment: @selbie, No, returned local values are moved out if possible when (N)RVO doesn't apply. `std::move` would be useful when returning an rvalue reference parameter.

Comment: @chris yes it's C++11. It's mostly avoiding memory leak because there are many such vectors in my code right now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that's the second best option I considered.

Comment: @Nandu that would make the code way uglier. I would rather use pointer/references instead of global vars.

Comment: @AmeerJewdaki, Then you're likely fine. Things returned by value are almost always moved out at worst and when that happens, you'll still have only one taking up the memory. The local object's memory will ideally just be reused for the return value, but if not that, you still won't end up with two copies of the same vector elements. The function's vector would be destroyed when the function ends, but at that point, the return value would have already cheaply stolen everything without copying more than a few bytes here and there.

Comment: @chris so effectively the content is not deleted until the end of `main()` right? if it was some other function, say `fun()` would the memory be released at the end of `fun()`?

Comment: @AmeerJewdaki, It's whenever the variable holding the return value goes out of scope, so yes, at the end of that function if you're done using it. In general, if you don't use `new`, things get cleaned up right when you're done with them. Even when you need dynamic memory allocation, if you use a smart pointer, it's cleaned up as soon as the smart pointer(s) are done with it, which depends on the type of smart pointer as to whether that's after one goes out of scope or all do.

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly how you're supposed to return objects -- by value. The compiler will apply NRVO optimizations to ensure no copying takes place.

Comment: Or even in the absence of RVO the objects will (in C++11 or later) be moved rather than copied.

Comment: Sure, but you'll be hard pressed in this day and age to have NRVO not apply (debug builds notwithstanding).

Comment: thanks, and I updated the post with an additional question, when is the allocated memory freed then in the example code?

Comment: @Blindy, It's not as hard as it sounds. For example, returning a by-value parameter.

Comment: @AmeerJewdaki when `main()` exits.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it like this:

```
void make_vect(vector<int> *dest)
{
    dest->resize(1000000); 
    ...      // some analysis
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    make_vect(&v);
}
```

Others would use a vector & instead of a vector *, but I think using the pointer indicates that the called function is expected to write into it.

Comment: It's the lack of `const` that indicates the writing into the parameter, unless you mean that the caller has to attach `&` to the argument, in which case I do find it a shame sometimes that non-const references are so transparent.

Comment: Yes, when I see make_vect(v), I expect the called function to only look at the value, whether it's copied or not.  make_vect(&v) indicates to me that the function will write into it.  I admit that this might be just because I'm old.

Comment: As far as I can remember, the extra syntax at the callsite is the main reason for the Google style guide using pointers over non-const references.

Answer (score 0):

Though both passing by value and using pointers would work in this specific instance, I wouldn't discount using pointers because they're a little more complicated. If you're doing any dynamic allocation, it might actually simplify your process to start with pointers now so you don't have to go back and change everything later. Just my two cents!